# How do I handle this API response in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an API error that I would like to have the JSON for.

I'm currently handling the response like this:

```
return fetch( 'https://api-prod.corelogic.com/property/' + propertyId + '/avm/thv/thvMarketingStandard', {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
  },
})
.then(function (resp) {

  console.log(resp)

  if(resp.status === 200 ){

    // Return the response as JSON
    return resp.json();         
  }else{
    return resp.text()
  }

}).then(function (data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data), data.toString())    
  return data
})
```

Returning the response as JSON was giving me nothing, so I returned it as text and got the following:

```
"<root>\n                    {\n                        \"errorCode\": \"429\",\n                        \"message\": \"Quota Exceeded\",\n                        \"description\": \"You have exceeded your daily quota for this application and orders will no longer be processed today. You will be able to resume testing tomorrow.\"\n                    }\n                </root>\n            " – "<root>↵                    {↵                        \"errorCode\": \"429\",↵                        \"message\": \"Quota Exceeded\",↵            …"
```

Is there any way I can parse this correctly into JSON?

Comment: look into the parse.Json function. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: @jgetner That throws an error because of ''<root>".

Comment: If you want to parse this as json, you're going to have to manipulate the string to string out the invalid parts.  We would need to see a more complete example for us to help you more.

Comment: Is it a public api? can you share the link if possible?

Comment: https://developer.corelogic.com/apis

Answer (score 0):

It appears the response is not valid JSON and is being returned in plaintext/html. Perhaps look at the returned header to see what the actual `Content-Type` is?

If you want a more clear response you could remove the large areas of whitespace in the the `response.text`.

Does the API you are using support JSON responses? Could you add a header in your request that asks for a JSON response?

Comment: All the other responses have been JSON. It says the response type is 'text/json'. I'm using the CoreLogic API https://developer.corelogic.com/apis

Comment: I guess my other thought would be could you remove the <root> at the front and possibly its closing tag or any other bloat and then is it valid json?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve the JSON by parsing the string as XML:

```
  .then(function (resp) {

      console.log(resp)

        if(resp.status === 200 ){

            // Return the response as JSON
            return resp.json();         
        }else{
            return resp.text();

        }


    }).then(function (data) {


        if(IsJsonString(data)){
            return data
        }else{
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const errorXML = parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml")
            const errorString  = errorXML.getElementsByTagName("root")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            const errorJSON = JSON.parse(errorString as string)
            console.log(errorJSON)
        }

    })
```